# Traversing a Dynamic Unordered List in GWT

Tags: java, html, gwt, html-lists

I'm making a program in GWT.

I'm using HTML to build an unordered list. It starts off empty and is dynamically added to through a javascript. Here is my empty unordered list:

```
<ul id="realList" style="list-style-type:none"></ul>
```

In my java GWT class, I have a button. When I click on it, I want it to traverse my ul ("realList") and return the id of each item in it. Here is the button:

```
final Button sendButton3 = new Button("GO", new ClickHandler() {
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        //Traversing the UL will go here
    }
});
```

Because I created my UL in my HTML, I'm not quite sure how to call it in my java GWT class - let alone traverse it. Any help on how to do this would be wildly appreciated. Let me know if any other code is necessary. Thanks!

Comment: Here is source code like an example of GWT app: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/GWTApplication.zip and GWT parser.

Comment: Base GWT doesn't include an un-ordered list widget, but why don't you just use a ListBox widget and write that into a named div in your HTML? Alternatively, you could use UiBinder to manipulate the ul you have (Google this. There are some examples out there.). I would go with the former approach, though.

Comment: @CBass how would you write the ListBox into the div?

Comment: @Yikes In your HTML create a div (or use a table cell or whatever) and give it an id, such as "holdMyListBox". Example: <td id="holdMyListBox"/>. Then in your GWT application java file's onModuleLoad() method, add a ListBox to that named container like this: RootPanel.get("holdMyListBox").add(myListBox); I'll add it as an answer.....

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base GWT does not have an unordered list widget so you can either modify your existing one through UIBinder or use a ListBox widget and write that into your HTML. To do that:

In your HTML create a div (or use a table cell or whatever) and give it an id, such as "holdMyListBox". Example:

`<td id="holdMyListBox"/>`

Then in your GWT application java file's onModuleLoad() method, add a ListBox to that named container like this:

```
RootPanel.get("holdMyListBox").add(myListBox);
```

Now you can do whatever you want to your list in your Java code. For example, you could have a list on objects that you use to both populate the ListBox and interrogate based on user selection.